# How do I display discounts for bulk-orders of a product in the product grid?

Tags: php, opencart

Working with **OpenCart** and the **Journal** template I have several products with bulk-order discounts. When displaying them in the product grid I would like to display the lowest discount price instead of the regular price (if a product has a discount).
I've understood the basics of OpenCart's MVC system, but I don't know the best way to access the discount data in the `category.tpl` file, since it's not part of `$product`.

Accessing discount data in `product.tpl` is done with the `$discounts` array. Can I make use of the `$this->journal2->settings->get()` function in `category.tpl` or do I need to tweak in the model to access the data?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add

```
$discounts_data = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($result['product_id']);
    $discounts = array();
    foreach ($discounts_data as $discount) {
        $discounts[] = array(
            'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
            'price'    => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency'])
            );
        }
```

before:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb'       => $image,
```

in category.php & add

```
'discount'    => $discounts,
```

after

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb'       => $image,
```

then you can access $discount for each product in category.tpl

Comment: So I edited `catalog/controller/product/category.php` as you said, but `isset($product['discount']) = false` in `category.tpl` when I try to access the data. Did I edit the wrong `category.php`?